# Add labels to a map using d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label

I am trying to create a map using d3js and label the point features with a particular attribute .Below is the code which I have tried and the labels doesnt seem to work.

What could I be doing wrong while trying to add the labels.Thank you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
    .land {
        stroke: #ff0f00;
        fill: none;
    }

    .state-boundary {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000fff;
    }

    .labels {
        fill: #444;
        font-family:arial;
        font-size:0.7em;
      }

   text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

</style>

<body>
    <script src="d3.v3.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var width = 1000,
            height = 900;

        var projection = d3.geo.albers()
            .scale(1000)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);


        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);



        d3.json("http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
            if (error) throw error;

            svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
                .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
                .attr("class", "land")
                .attr("d", path);

            svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
                .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
                    return a !== b;
                }))
                .attr("class", "state-boundary")
                .attr("d", path);
        });

        d3.csv("nfl_teams.csv", function(error, data) {
            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {
                    return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
                })
                .attr("cy", function(d) {
                    return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1];
                })
                .attr("r", 15)
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke", "red");

            svg.selectAll(".labels")
              .data(data)
              .enter().append("text")
              .attr("class", "labels")
              .text(function(d) { return d.properties.Team; })
              .attr("x", function(d) {
                  return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[0];
              })
              .attr("y", function(d) {
                  return projection([d.Longitude, d.Latitude])[1];
              })

               });



        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");
    </script>
```

nfl_teams.csv

```
Team,Latitude,Longitude
Chicago,41.53,-87.38
Green Bay,44.3,-88.01
Arizona,33.27,-112.05
Atlanta,33.45,-84.23
Baltimore,39.17,-76.37
Buffalo,42.54,-78.53
Carolina,35.14,-80.5
Cincinnati,39.06,-84.31
Cleveland,41.3,-81.41
Dallas,32.47,-96.48
Denver,39.43,-105.01
Detroit,42.2,-83.03
Houston,29.46,-95.22
Indianapolis,39.46,-86.09
Jacksonville,30.2,-81.4
Kansas City,39.06,-94.37
Miami,25.46,-80.12
Minnesota,44.59,-93.13
New England,42.21,-71.04
New Orleans,29.58,-90.07
New York Giants,40.43,-74.01
New York Jets,40.43,-74.01
Oakland,37.47,-122.13
Philadelphia,39.57,-75.07
Pittsburgh,40.26,-80
LA Rams,38.38,-90.11
San Diego,32.43,-118.09
San Francisco,37.48,-122.24
Seattle,47.36,-122.2
Tampa,27.57,-82.27
Tennessee,36.09,-86.48
Washington,38.54,-77.01
```

Comment: Are the circles showing up? The problem is just the labels?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado the circles come up fine . Its just the labels.

Comment: In that case, can you paste "nfl_teams.csv"? Just a couple of rows.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I have attached it here.

Comment: Thanks, the fix is simple: it's `d.Team`, not `d.properties.Team`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is your CSV:

```
Team,Latitude,Longitude
Chicago,41.53,-87.38
Green Bay,44.3,-88.01
```

That will be your data array after `d3.csv` function loads the data:

```
[{
    Team: "Chicago",
    Latitude: "41.53",
    Longitude: "-87.38"
}, {
    Team: "Green Bay",
    Latitude: "44.3",
    Longitude: "-88.01"
},{
    ...
}]
```

As you can see, you don't have any key named `properties` in your data objects. Thus, the fix is simple. Instead of:

```
.text(function(d) { return d.properties.Team; })
```

It should be:

```
.text(function(d) { return d.Team; })
```